# Replace all characters from every row in column, with a word

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a column in MS Access, that has multiple unique values.
All values are ending with a number.
Something like this:

- Kostas No.23
- Stel ios No.1
- Pavlos No.649
- asd fds qwe No.287

I want to rename all the values like that:

- TR - 23
- TR - 1
- TR - 649
- TR - 287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update using this expression in your update query:

```
"TR - " & Mid([YourField], InStr([YourField], " No.") + Len(" No."))
```

The full SQL could be like this:

```
UPDATE
    prod_6
SET 
    [ref] = "TR - " & Mid([ref], InStr([ref], " No.") + Len(" No."))
```

and you may wish to add a filter to prevent more than one update:

```
UPDATE
    prod_6
SET 
    [ref] = "TR - " & Mid([ref], InStr([ref], " No.") + Len(" No."))
WHERE
    [ref] Not Like "TR - *"
```

Comment: Thank's for the response. It happens that i am a true beginner with Access, though i have some very small experience with sql - (with mysql). Could you please give me the full query?  I get an error with that :

UPDATE prod_6
 "TR - " & Mid([ref], InStr([ref], " No.") + Len(" No."));

Comment: Yes. See extended answer, please.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. Thumbs up! :)